# "type" not working in R plot function with ecdf object

Tags: r, plot, types, frequency-distribution

My aim is to generate a cumulative distribution function made with steps, using the parameter `type="s"`, but when i try for example

```
plot(ecdf(rgeom(0:40,0.3)), type="s")
```

it says the error

```
Error in plot.default(NA, NA, type = "n", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, xlab = xlab,  : formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

What to do?

Comment: `ecdf` has its own plotting method; see `?plot.ecdf`. Adjust as you like, e.g. `plot(ecdf(rgeom(0:40,0.3)), verticals = TRUE, pch = NA, col.01line = NA)`

Comment: Try this `curve(ecdf(rgeom(0:40,0.3))(x), from = 0, to = 40, type = "s")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead try:

```
plot(ecdf(rgeom(0:40,0.3)),verticals = TRUE)
```

In this case `plot` dispatches to `plot.ecdf` which in turn calls `plot.stepfun`. `plot.stepfun` initializes a plot using a call to `plot()` that specifies `type = "n"`, hence the conflict in `type` arguments.

The `verticals` argument is from `plot.ecdf` and so it gets passed along happily without any conflicts.

Comment: Ok so in which case can i use `type="n"` and for which kind of plots?

Comment: @Poli The only way to know for sure is to look carefully at the documentation & code for each `plot` method.